# Screenshot of window in Java

Tags: java, selenium, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a browser window in Java in a Selenium-automated test. For most steps, AShot works (using viewportPasting), but one step in particular has a browser-induced popup window and using AShot crashes the step. For reference, the popup cannot be inspected so I'm guessing it's a result of a JS process, and it's cleared with `driver.switchTo().alert().accept()`.

I've also tried `Robot().createScreenCapture` but that takes the whole screen rather than just the window.